# Getting 404 when calling delete method from an iframe

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

I'm attempting to call a delete method on user click

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
                    " ",
                       "DeleteAttachment",
                    new { attachmentid = item.bookingattachmentid },
                    new {
                        @class = "buttondelete" 
                })
```

the correct url is displayed when I mouse over the delete link...

```
 http://localhost:53712/Booking/DeleteAttachment?attachmentid=51693
```

but on click, the server responds with "The resource cannot be found."

Searching Google, I haven't found anything saying I can't call the delete post from an iframe. The source of the iframe is the same domain as the parent.

this is the controller action

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string DeleteAttachment(int bookingattachmentid)
    {
        bookingattachment bookingattachment = db.bookingattachments.Find(bookingattachmentid);
        db.bookingattachments.Remove(bookingattachment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Could you show how your controller action look like? Could it be by any chance decorated with the `[HttpDelete]` or `[HttpPost]` attribute? Also what happens if you put this url in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: yes, I've updated the question - same result, but I believe that's because its a GET, right? I get 404 on any delete method I put directly in the browser url.

Comment: Yes, it's because an anchor sends GET verb. If you want to be able to invoke this controller action the client needs to use the POST verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your controller action is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` verb. So in order to invoke it you need to use the `POST` HTTP verb. In ASP.NET MVC, an `Html.ActionLink` generates an anchor which in turn uses the `GET` verb. That's why you are getting a 404.

If you want to be able to invoke this controller action you could rather use an HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteAttachment", "Booking", new { attachmentid = item.bookingattachmentid }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" class="buttondelete" value="Delete Attachment" />
}
```

If you don't want to use an HTML `<form>` you might consider using AJAX in order to call your controller action as it allows you to use POST verb:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    linkText: " ", 
    actionName: "DeleteAttachment", 
    controllerName: "Booking", 
    routeValues: new { attachmentid = item.bookingattachmentid }, 
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }
)
```